# How to add a parameter in my PHP code

Tags: php, wordpress

I got this simple line: `get_comments( 'post_id='.$newpost->ID.'');` based on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments

It works fine but I would like to order the posts in a different order.
I've tried a lot of ways of writting it but it never seems to work.

How would I add one of these parameters?:

> $orderby (string) (optional) Set the field used to sort comments.
>   Default: comment_date_gmt $order (string) (optional) How to sort
>
> $orderby. Valid values: 'ASC' - Ascending (lowest to highest). 'DESC'
>   - Descending (highest to lowest). Default: DESC

Thanks for your help you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an array with your variables:

```
get_comments( array('orderby' => 'ID', 'order' => 'ASC', 'post_id' => $newpost->ID) );
```